# Create, update and sync

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi guys i need a to create a tool but before  i need to know if there is something similar available on the web. I have many supliers that send me products in formatos like csv and xls. Each client send the strcture csv in there own  way, i need to relate with my store and of course Keep updating it daily, Is there a script available out there?

I cant find anything relevante that meets my requirwments

Comment: I don't think so. Logic in files could be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

To do it simply, take the data and put into simple SKU, PRICE csv and upload directly using Magmi, takes sections to upload as its direct to the db.

For a more complex setup, if your suppliers supply a CSV feed, get the data store it locally, then run Magmi via the cron, thats what I do.

Comment: Magmi is free tool to upload direct to DB. UnderstadingE did their own mix on it, and it was free but since changed. Let me know if you need any help